# Setup project for wpf application

Tags: wpf, dependencies, setup-project

I am trying to build a setup-msi using visual studio for my wpf application.
The issue i am facing is that i force primary output from wpf project to the setup project
and the dependencies are calcaluted automatically.
I run the msi locally (on the machine i built the wpf app) and everything works fine.

The problems start when i try to install it on different machines.
On other machines i run the installation process and it finishes justfine
but when i try to run the application i get exceptions about assemblies that could not be found.(e.g System.Web , Version=4,0,0,0 could not be found etc)

I really suck building setup projects but can anybody give a hand?

P.S.: I also tried installShield... same results.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the target machine only had .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile installed. System.Web is in .NET Framework 4.0 Extended, which is installed with the full 4.0 Framework but not with the Client Profile.

Are you bootstrapping .NET 4 in your setup?

Check for the presence of "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile" and "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended" in Add/Remove Programs (XP) or Programs and Features (Vista/7) on the machines where the application ran fine and those where it gave that error.

**Edit**: [.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee942965%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). That should help you figure out how best to deploy it.

Comment: I suppose that this is going to be the problem. The bigger problem that i have is that the end users dont have a clue of how to install things.
I really want to see their faces when i'll tell them, "you have to install .Net 4.0 framework".

I dont really know how to incluse .Net Framework on the setup.
Do you know any tutorial on this?

This is my first app using c# wpf and i dont know anything about publishing so be patient if i said anything stupid.

Comment: Is your app actually using anything in System.Web? I would think the odds of that would be a bit slim in someone's first WPF app.

Comment: Well it actually does. I have created an encryption schema in order to activate the end user product. This schema involves a communication with a server for which i use the System.Web. 
This is my first Wpf app but it doesn't really mean that this is my first app :P

By the way that was the actual problem.You are correct.Thanks for the guide it works smoothly now..

Comment: Didn't mean to imply it was your first ever. I just tend to think in a different way (my first production WPF apps were small-ish tools; starting with smaller MVVM projects made it easier for me to learn and still get stuff working).

Comment: well thats the best possible approach...but when the client wants ,he should get.And lets dont discuss about the deadlines.